# Kind mis-match in instance of Maybe

Tags: haskell

I have a definition of class

```
class Functor f  => Pointed f where
    pure :: a -> f a
```

And now I would like to make instance for `Maybe`. Why doesn't this work?

```
instance Pointed (Maybe s) where
    pure Nothing  = Nothing
    pure (Just a) =  a


class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a->b) -> f a -> f b
```

Error is:

```
  Kind mis-match
    The first argument of `Pointed' should have kind `* -> *',
    but `Maybe s' has kind `*'
    In the instance declaration for `Pointed (Maybe s)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the definition of `Pointed`, `f` has kind `* -> *` so you need to provide a type constructor with the same kind. `Maybe` has that kind, while `(Maybe s)` has kind `*`. If you substitute `Maybe` for `f` in the definition of `pure` you get:

```
pure :: a -> Maybe a
```

Your definition should therefore look like:

```
instance Pointed Maybe where
    pure a =  Just a
```

The kind `* -> *` is inferred for `f` due to the rules for [kind inference](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-970004.6). `a` is assumed to have kind `*` as it is a function parameter (which has kind `* -> * -> *`). `f a` should have kind `*` so `f` has kind `* -> *`.

In the definition of `Pointed`, `Functor f =>` is a class context and declares that `Functor` is a superclass of `Pointed`. This means that all instances of `Pointed` must also be instances of `Functor`.

`Maybe` is already an instance of `Functor` so you don't need to define it yourself.

Comment: I can't see why `In the definition of Pointed, f has kind * -> *`
I am sorry, I forgot to give a Functor definition. I edited post. Especially, what does it mean exactly?: `class Functor f  => Pointed f` Is difference between Functor (f) and Functor f?

Comment: @Gilgamesz Because the term `f a` is present in the type of `pure`.

Comment: Ok, you are right. But please answer too:
What does it mean exactly?: `class Functor f => Pointed f` Is difference between `Functor (f)` and `Functor f`?